# Send a RepeaterItem Object with HyperLink to other page

Tags: html, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery-mobile and asp. Is there any way to place the `ID` in the hyperlink? I can show the `ID` using `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")` but don't know how to place it in the NavigateUrl like this: `NavigateUrl="Details.aspx?ID"`

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <ul style="position:relative;top:30px" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyp" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Details.aspx">
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
                          <span class="ui-li-count"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %></span>
                                   </asp:HyperLink>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:Repeater>
               </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your huperlink with this one

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "Details.aspx?ID=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>'>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
                          <span class="ui-li-count"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %></span>
                                    </asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: I get: `The server tag is not well formed.`

Comment: NavigateUrl='Details.aspx?ID=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>' in single quote

Comment: I used single quote. The URL looks like this: `Details.aspx?ID=%3C%#%20DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,%20%22ID%22)%20%%3E`